# How to add current user as foreign key in Django serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing a Serializer for my log model which contain User as a foreign key. How can I add the current user in log Serializer.
Here is my log model:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    title = models.TextField(null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    impact = models.IntegerField()
    ease = models.IntegerField()
    confidence = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title},{self.pk}"
```

Here is my log serializer:

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='user.id' ,queryset=User.objects.all(), many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ['id','user','title','ease','impact','confidence']
```

but this is giving validation error.
"user": [
"This field is required."
]

Here is my views:

```
class logsApiView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, id=None,format=None):
        data = request.data
        serializer = LogSerializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        print('hey')
        serializer.save()
        response = Response()

        response.data = {
            'message': 'Todo Created Successfully',
            'data': serializer.data
        }

        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering, "user": ["This field is required."], is occurring because you've defined the `user` field in your `LogSerializer` as a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`. This field expects a valid primary key for the `User` model, and since it's not provided in the request data, it raises a validation error.

To automatically set the `user` field in your `Log` model to the currently authenticated user when creating a new log entry, you can override the `create` method of your serializer. You don't need to include the `user` field in the serializer's fields explicitly.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Log

class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Log
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'ease', 'impact', 'confidence']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Get the currently authenticated user
        user = self.context['request'].user

        # Create a new log entry with the user
        log = Log.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)

        return log
```

In the `create` method, we access the currently authenticated user using `self.context['request'].user` and then create a new `Log` instance with the user and the validated data.

With this setup, when you create a new log entry, the `user` field will be automatically set to the currently authenticated user without requiring it in the request data. Your view remains the same:

```py
class logsApiView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, id=None, format=None):
        data = request.data
        serializer = LogSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        response = Response({
            'message': 'Log Created Successfully',
            'data': serializer.data
        })

        return response
```

Now, the user will be associated with the log entry based on the currently authenticated user when creating a new log through your API.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because your API is not updating the user field.

You can correct this error by getting the request user and passing it as a parameter in the `.save()` method.

```
class logsApiView(APIView):
def post(self, request, id=None,format=None):
    data = request.data
    serializer = LogSerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    print('hey')
    
    # Get request user
    request_user = request.user

    serializer.save(user=request_user) # set the user field
    response = Response()

    response.data = {
        'message': 'Todo Created Successfully',
        'data': serializer.data
    }

    return response
```

This will solve the problem.

You can go ahead to remove `user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='user.id' ,queryset=User.objects.all(), many=False)`  from your LogSerializer.

```
class LogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='user.id' ,queryset=User.objects.all(), many=False) # Remove this part or comment it out
class Meta:
    model = Log
    fields = ['id','user','title','ease','impact','confidence']
```